# Is the direct product $H \times K$ necessarily a central extension of $H$ by $K$ or $K$ by $H$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, direct-product, group-extensions

As far as I know, a central + split extension of a group $K$ by a group $H$ is uniquely the direct product $H \times K$. But is the other direction true as well? That is, is any direct product necessarily a central and split extension?

I don't think so. Consider two non-abelian groups $H$ and $K$. And consider the direct product $H \times K$. A non-abelian group can never lie in the center of another group (because the center of any group is abelian). So neither $H$ nor $K$ can lie in the center of $H \times K$. But then $H \times K$ can't be a central extension of $H$ by $K$ or $K$ by $H$, isn't it? Could someone please clarify?

Comment: What is the definition of central extension that you know?

Comment: A direct product is necessarily a split extension.

Comment: Central extensions need not be split extensions, and split extensions need not be central extensions. They are different concepts. A direct product is always a split extensions, but is only a central extension if one of the factors is abelian, and then it is only a central extension if you consider it as an extension of the abelian factor by the other factor.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks, that answers my question I think

Comment: @Sky: Note: it’s possible for $K\times H$ to be a central extension even if neither $K$ nor $H$ are abelian, but it won’t be a central extension of $K$ by $H$ (or of $H$ by $K$). For instance, $(C_2\times S_3)\times S_3$ is a central extension of C_2$ by $S_3\times S_3$.